# How does one generate a random $N \times N$ density matrix with quaternionic entries -- with respect to Hilbert-Schmidt measure?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, computational-physics, probability, density-operator

In the article

https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.5094

the formula (eq. (1))
\begin{equation}
\rho_{HS} =\frac{A A^{\dagger}}{\mbox{Tr} A A^{\dagger}}
\end{equation}
is given, for generating a random $N \times N$ density matrix ($\rho_{HS}$) with complex off-diagonal entries with respect to Hilbert-Schmidt (HS) measure. ("The HS measure is defined by the HS metric $\mbox{d}s^2_{HS} =\frac{1}{2} \mbox{Tr}[(\mbox{d}\rho)^2]$, which is distinguished by the fact that it induces the flat, Euclidean geometry into the set of mixed states." A density matrix is a positive semidefinite, hermitian matrix of trace 1.)

Here $A$ is a square complex random matrix of size N pertaining to the Ginibre ensemble (with real and imaginary parts of each element being independent normal random variables).

Now, if one similarly wants a random $N \times N$ density matrix with real off-diagonal entries, the matrix $A$  (with each element now being an independent normal random variable) is chosen to be of dimensions $N \times (N+1)$ (bot. p. 9 of indicated article).

So, I want to find the appropriate analogous procedure to employ when the off-diagonal entries of the density matrix are quaternions.

I've been investigating this question with $N=4$, where I anticipate the associated "separability probability" will be $\frac{26}{323}$. (In the real case, this Hilbert-Schmidt probability has recently been proven by Lovas and Andai [https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.01410.pdf] to be  $\frac{29}{64}$ and, in the complex case to be $\frac{8}{33}$ in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.01973.pdf . For the $\frac{26}{323}$ assertion, see http://iopscience.iop.org.proxy.library.ucsb.edu:2048/article/10.1088/1751-8113/46/44/445302/pdf .)

I don't seem to be able to succeed numerically getting near this $\frac{26}{323}$ value by choosing $A$ to have similarly random quaternionic entries and be of dimension $4 \times M$, where $M$ is some integer (3, 4, 5...). To test separability, one needs to evaluate whether the partial transpose of the density matrix is positive definite. This test can be accomplished in the $4 \times 4$ case by testing the positivity of the determinant of the partial transpose. In the (non-commutative) quaternionic case, I've been using what is termed the "Moore determinant" [Bull. Amer. Math. Soc 28 (1922): 161-162] for this purpose.

Perhaps it may be necessary to convert the $4 \times 4$ matrices A with quaternionic entries to $8 \times 8$ complex form (using the well-known quaternion-to-Pauli matrices conversion rules) and proceed using the formula above. Then, possibly convert back to $4 \times 4$ quaternionic form.

In these last regards, I've  posted a Mathematica question

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148841/

concerning how to efficiently go back and forth between these $4 \times 4$ and $8 \times 8$ structures.

Comment: Could you supply a source for the claim that the positivity of the determinant of the partial transpose is a test for separability? 

Also, is it known that the Peres-Horodecki condition applies to quaternionic 4x4 matrices?

Comment: Thanks, Joel Klassen. As to your first question, see eq. (2) in the paper "Universal observable detecting all two-qubit entanglement and determinant-based
separability tests", https://journals.aps.org/pra/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevA.77.030301. As to your second highly relevant question, I presently plead ignorance, but will further investigate/cogitate. Perhaps I should incorporate these points into the original question.

Comment: As to the second question of Joel Klassen, see sec. 4 of the paper of Fei and Joynt https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.1993.pdf   ,  also  http://ac.els cdn.com.proxy.library.ucsb.edu:2048/S0034487716300611/1-s2.0-S0034487716300611-main.pdf?_tid=52a523e8-58e2-11e7-8918-00000aab0f02&acdnat=1498311653_54b2d1c34e78785661eaa556271bccfd

Comment: Thanks Paul B. Slater! This all sounds quite interesting, I wish I could be of more help to you.

Comment: Well, as a research project of current interest, I could suggest using the (computationally-intensive) Fei-Joynt procedure to generate random two-quaterbit density matrices, and using them to test the conjecture that the corresponding “Lovas-Andai function” $\tilde{\chi_4}(\varepsilon)$ is $\varepsilon^4 (2-\varepsilon^4)$—a function which, in the Lovas-Andai framework, yields the presumed \frac{26}{323}$ Hilbert-Schmidt separability probability. (See the two cited preprints in the statement of the question for more details.)

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v7): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.

Comment: I don't understand a lot of what's written here, but usually if one is trying to generalize this sort of thing to the quaternions, it's either straightforward (use the same formulas as for the complex numbers, being careful to avoid using the commutative law) or impossible (usually because commutativity is required).

Comment: Thanks, J. Baez. Well, I can apparently do the (matrix multiplication) calculations ($A A^{\dagger}$) , using the NonCommutativeMultiply (**) feature of Mathematica, but for matrices A of dimension 4 x N (N=2,.3,...), I don't come very close to obtaining this auxiliary separability probability of 26/323, that an elegant body of prior analyses indicates should be the case. (Of course, one might now argue that this brings the 26/323 result itself into question--or even the manner [using the Moore determinant] of obtaining the result.)

Comment: Well, I had been led by the reference in the second comment above  and certain prior analyses to believe if was sufficient to test the positivity of the (Moore) determinant of the partial transpose to ensure its (full) positivity. But I will now (prompted somewhat by the remark of J. Baez) investigate whether one also needs to additionally test the positivity of the $2 \times 2$ and $3 \times 3$ prinicipal minors (again using the Moore determinant for hermitian matrices). If, in fact, necessary, doing so should help to reduce the (apparently too large) separability probability estimates.